# Error When printing using vb.net crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net

when run application some report working fine 
and other show this message error

when enter start date and end date with search name

Like Photo here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WannK.png

how to solve this problem

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
   at Amr.DataBase.Reports.frmReportView.Init(String rptFile, String SelectionFormula, String sTitle, String[,] Formulas, String dbFile, String password)


   at Amr.DataBase.Reports....(Object ., EventArgs )
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing assembly reference CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.

Comment: i setup CR10AdvDevEn.exe crystal report 10 but still error